# React setstate nested object issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, setstate

I am not able to solve this setState second night and I'm already desperate. I have heavily nested object which I'm trying to update. In case I have multiple elements in todaysMenu and I'm trying to update state for second element whole array gets "stored" in first element of todaysMenu.

```
onChangeAnyValue(values, itemIndex) {
        const key = Object.keys(values.x)[0];
        const provideDate = values.date;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            data: prevState.data.map(day => day.date === provideDate ? {
                ...day,
                todaysMenu: [{
                    ...day.todaysMenu,
                    [itemIndex]: {
                        ...day.todaysMenu[itemIndex],
                        dish: {
                            ...day.todaysMenu[itemIndex].dish,
                            [key]: values.x[key]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            } : day)
        }));
    }
```

In case I remove square brackets its stored as just objects.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change:

```
todaysMenu: [{
  ...day.todaysMenu,
  [itemIndex]: {
    ...day.todaysMenu[itemIndex],
    dish: {
      ...day.todaysMenu[itemIndex].dish,
      [key]: values.x[key]
    }
  }
}]
```

...to:

```
todaysMenu: day.todaysMenu.map((item, index) => 
  index === itemIndex
    ? { ...item, dish: { ...item.dish, [key]: values.x[key] } }
    : item
)
```

What you currently have is creating an Array with one object instead of converting an Array to a modified Array.